# React Native v5, Android 9 - Touch events not triggered

Tags: android, react-native

I created a new react native project using expo bare workflow and installed react native v5.

On iOS it is working fine.

But on Android, no touch events are being triggered.  Swiping is getting through though.

Any ideas why this might be happening ?

Comment: can we see some code?

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you are importing `TouchableOpacity` or any touchable elements from another library and not from `react-native` itself. Most likely you're importing it from `react-native-gesture-handler`.

I encountered this problem before and it solved it for me.